# pressing Q should be Q + MB RightClick

Tags: autohotkey

I was wondering if this can be done in AutoHotKey that whenever I press *Q* the output should be *Q and mouse right click*. I tried 
`Q::MouseClick, right` but this doesnt do the *Q* keystroke. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add `~` before the Q

Comment: Thanks [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1398418/oleg). You really saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

As well as ~ you can send the ASCII character

```
q::
Send, {Asc 113}
mouseclick, right
return
```